# How to find court records for Pennsylvania child support orders

Tags: pennsylvania, court-records, child-support

I have been getting emails sent by the state of Pennsylvania about missed mandatory court ordered child support payments that my estranged father is apparently supposed to be making.   I am trying to find out whatever details I can.

My research so far:  on [what is public record](https://www.pacourts.us/assets/opinions/Supreme/out/477jad-attach2.pdf) it says for domestic relations: child support payments that there is  "No Public Access, except for
PACSES dockets, court orders
and opinions.", which implies there is some form of public record available.

On [link for searching pa courts](https://ujsportal.pacourts.us/CaseInformation.aspx) I have no idea which court to search for or what fields to put my father's information in.

Obviously not looking for legal advice, just help navigating the Pennsylvania court records search.

Comment: If you are a party to these court orders then you are not "public" and should be able to get access.

Comment: I don't think I should be a party,  I am receiving emails to my personal email account that are addressed to my father's name.  @jwh20

Comment: The emails would ordinarily reference a case name and case number and make it possible to determine the court given what you know about where your father and his children lived at the pertinent times. Call the clerk of the court once you have that information.